# Android - How to show an exact location on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm building an android app for a store, the problem is that I'm unable to show that store on a map, I want to show something like this (with the store name) :
[image]
I have tried two ways :
1) getting the long & lat from google maps and setting the camera to that location :

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(MY_LAT, MY_LONG);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 20));
```

2) using the the GEOCODER :

```
Address address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(MY_ADRESS, 1).get(0);
LatLng location = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 20));
```

in both cases it shows the wrong place (not what I want) (the geocoder returns only one address, I checked the list size).
I believe there is a better way to do that, any suggestions please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

So the only solution I found is to search place by id, here is how you can do that :
1) get the place id from [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-placeid-finder) (if you're business doesn't show in the map, then I can't help, if anyone knows how to solve that, please tell us)
[image]
In the following I will suppose that you copied the place id and stored it a a constant named : YOUR_PLACE_ID
2) Enable Google Places API for Android on your project : https://console.cloud.google.com/home (I suppose that you already created a google project for your app and have Google maps api already enabled)
3) add  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'` (11.0.4 is the current version) to your build.gradle (app)

4) add the required permission in your AndroidManifests.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

4) declare an instance variable in your class : `GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient ;`
5) Initialize it in your onCreate (for example) :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API).build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

6) get the place coordinates :

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, YOUR_PLACE_ID)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                    LatLng location = places.get(0).getLatLng();
                    if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this,"Place coordinates :" + location,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this,"Failed to get the location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    places.release();
                }
            });
```